# applicationProtectedDataDidBecomeAvailable does not get called after locking device for over 2 minutes

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, appdelegate, data-protection

My app depends on `applicationProtectedDataDidBecomeAvailable` being called but i've noticed that if I lock my device and wait for around 3 minutes and unlock it then `applicationProtectedDataDidBecomeAvailable` doesn't get called. Also when does `applicationProtectedDataDidBecomeAvailable` get called as opposed to `applicationWillEnterForeground` because I've noticed that when it does get called sometimes the order of these calls are random

Thanks guys

Comment: Hi, if it's not get called maybe data still available? Probably there is no randomness but different scenarios and reasons behind call orders of this methods. Could even changes in iOS versions. Can you try to log to in console to see behaviours and share some code please?

Comment: luckily there is no code, there is just a print statement inside of `applicationProtectedDataDidBecomeAvailable` and inside `applicationProtectedDataWillBecomeUnavailable`.